# How to get time difference (in hours) between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am trying to get the time difference between 2 users, I need the difference in hours.

I tried to use DATEDIFF function but it's wrong.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(*,  
(SELECT max(u1.time_c)
FROM users u)
,
(SELECT max(u2.time_c)
FROM users u2)
```

Comment: What do you mean "*the time difference between 2 users*"?  Are you referring to their timezones?  Or something else?  You say your existing code is "*wrong*" but don't say what's wrong with it.  Are we supposed to guess?  (My guess would be that [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function returns a difference in *days*, not *hours*; and only takes two arguments, not three--but is that *all* that's wrong?).

Comment: if u.1 was created 2 days ago and u.2 was created yesterday then the difference is 24 hours for example

Comment: Not clear. Add more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a `from` clause in your select statement.
Something like

```
Select date1 - date2 from dual
```

returns number of days between date1 and date2.

If you want number of hours:

```
Select (date1 - date2)*24 from dual;
```

*(this is only for oracle)*

Comment: I don't understand your question, but if you asking about the type of result, the result is a floating point number, wich represents the number of days in the first query, and the number of hours in the second. For example, 0.5 days means 12 hours. another example: 0.2 hours = 0.2*60 minutes = 12 minutes

Comment: If date difference is zero then what happen? how can get hour?

Comment: in this case nothing happens. There will be zero hours.

Answer (score 16):

From [MySQL DATEDIFF docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

```
Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.
```

You will want to look at [`TIMEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

This will give you the number of hours in the difference in times (assuming your `time_c` fields are DATETIME or something similar)

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(  
  (SELECT max(u1.time_c) FROM users u),
  (SELECT max(u2.time_c) FROM users u2)
))
```